# Add a profile picture in user registration page in Liferay

Tags: liferay

I want to add a profile picture while creating an account.....we can get this while editing the myaccount but i want this while creating account. Is there any way of doing this using the default Liferay User registration page?

Answer (score 0):

Make it as a wizard. Before all you ask default user data to register new user. When the new user is created, put a second step to upload the avatar.